# Special character shows in email body during use of elastic-bean stalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gmail, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

Is there anything to modified or configuration on Elastic bean stalk for setting of encoding?? Special character shows in my email body using elastic bean stalk.

Comment: Which emails are you talking about? Are they being sent by EBS itself, or through another service like SNS or SES?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk on its own does not have anything to do with your email body or encoding. Elastic Beanstalk is simply a tool that allows you to rapidly and easily deploy your application to the cloud. All configuration, encoding, etc. are within your application, not EB.

You haven't mentioned any details about your application. But it seems to be some sort of an application that sends an email. When generating and sending your email, you have to check what encoding you are using. Details vary depending on what language/platform/technology you have used.

To emphasize again, if you are trying to find the root cause of your problem inside Elastic Beanstalk, you are searching in vein, it has nothing to do with you application configurations such as encoding.

Comment: Actually We have an application that sends email to massive number of users. For this we have used aws sqs queue server and aws elastic-beanstalk. But while sending email with unicode character it shows special character in sent email.when i use local or dev server it shows actual character  but if i use production server that of AWS problem arises.

I have use JVM command line options: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8. @Sepehr Samiei

Comment: That may be because of your OS differences or even potentially different jdk versions. One of the most popular solutions to avoid run-time differences in various environments is using containers. You could easily containerize your application and deploy it anywhere you wish. Elastic Beanstalk supports containers as well. As another tip, you could use AWS SES to send massive number of emails. However, that's off this topic.